# Swift - Redraw Alternate Cells Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have an issue with displaying UICollectionView cells correctly. I need to display alternate colors in every even indexed cell, which works perfectly. Problem comes, if I add another cell, or clear to default set up -  it's all messed up:

[image: Default set up]

[image: Added new cell]

[image: Reset to Default]

I am subclassing the cell:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.addBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Center
    self.addBtn.contentVerticalAlignment = .Center

}
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    //---- Grad Fill

    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = txtField.superview!.superview as! UICollectionViewCell
    let table: UICollectionView = cell.superview as! UICollectionView
    let indexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)

    // fill every even cell
    if (((indexPath?.row)! % 2) == 0) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let locations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

        let colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]

        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, colors, locations)

        let startPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.height)
        let endPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context,gradient,startPoint,endPoint, .DrawsBeforeStartLocation)
    }
    else{

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

}
```

And then calling setNeedsDisplay() from button actions:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.collectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

What have I missed here please? I am sure it's something trivial...Also, when device rotates to landscape mode, collection view does not stretch accordingly. I am calling same method from:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    //self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 70)

    self.collectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Can Somebody point me to the right direction please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach. As a rule of thumb, avoid overriding drawRect. The rendering hardware on iOS devices works much more efficiently if you let views draw themselves.

Instead, configure your cells in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. Set the background color based on the index. Always set the background color explicitly. Don't assume it starts out with the default color, because for a recycled cell it probably won't.

When you add or delete cells you will need to either force the whole collection to reload or write code that figures out which cells need to be updated and sends a `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` message to the collection view with an array of the cells that need to be redrawn.